# Postgres not following search_path to locate tables

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, psql

I'm not sure the exact point at which this starting happening ( I believe it may have been after launching pgadmin3 for the first time ). Basically this seemed to happen all of a sudden and everything seems to be configured correctly..

PostgreSQL seems to no longer be following the search_path to locate my tables.

```
\d
No relations found.
```

My search path has been set (persistently at that):

```
SHOW search_path;
"public, myschema1, myschema2"
(1 row)
```

Not only am I the owner of the tables in question, I have run:

```
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public to myusername;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA myschema1 to myusername;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA myschema2 to myusername;
```

The data is all there. I can see the schemas when running a \dn. I can also run queries if I fully qualify the schema and table names. The biggest issue is that already created functions that reference an unqualified table name won't work.

Can anyone think of something I might not have tried? Any thoughts as to what caused this issue to start happening?

Thanks for any help!
-hightech

Comment: I don't have enough points to mark this answered myself yet, but:
The issue was with my search_path. It was set using quotes, which makes postgres think thats the full name of a schema... The correct command is:
    SET search_path = public, myschema1, myschema2
NOT
    SET search_path = 'public, myschema1, myschema2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you entered search_path as one string

```
postgres=# set search_path to public, s1;
SET
postgres=# show search_path ;
 search_path 
-------------
 public, s1
(1 row)

postgres=# set search_path to 'public, s1';
SET
postgres=# show search_path ;
 search_path  
--------------
 "public, s1"
(1 row)
```

second setting is wrong and doesn't work.

Comment: No, you should be able to see all tables in schemas that are in your search_path.

Comment: @hightech, you has a true, there is different bug.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a similar issue by **GRANT**ing that user **USAGE ON SCHEMA**, logged on as the **OWNER** on that schema. Let me develop:

User story: I could reproduce this strange behaviour with Postgres 9.6, see console output below. How bizarre was that? I could `\dt preprod.users`, but `\dt` only will not issue anything! I could also SELECT on these tables, which was really confusing me.

*(In search_path, note the space after the comma, automatically adjusted by PostgreSQL)*

```
do_preprod=> -- I'm logged on as preprod_www_ro, a read-only user who belongs to readonly ROLE.
do_preprod=> SET search_path TO preprod,public;
SET
do_preprod=> SHOW search_path;
   search_path
-----------------
 preprod, public
(1 row)
do_preprod=> \dt
Did not find any relations.
do_preprod=> \dt users;
Did not find any relation named "users".
do_preprod=> \dt preprod.users;
           List of relations
 Schema  | Name  | Type  |    Owner
---------+-------+-------+-------------
 preprod | users | table | preprod_www
(1 row)
```

Then, logged on as `preprod_www` (= schema owner), I GRANTed the `readonly` ROLE (`preprod_www_ro`'s) the `USAGE` privilege.
    do_preprod=> GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA preprod TO readonly;

Then, back as `preprod_www_ro`, I could immediately see the relations with `\dt`, enjoying fully my `search_path`, without having to log out log back in.

I would have liked a clearer message from PostgreSQL in the first place, when issuing `\dt`, or `\dt preprod.users`: "No USAGE ON SCHEMA granted..." or something like that, as in fact that user COULD use it...but not entirely smoothly.